# How to enable Two Factor Authentication for Customer Accounts

Tags: magento2, module, customer-account, security, two-factor-authentication

I would like to enable two-factor-authentication for Customer Accounts, but as per the documentation (https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/extension-install-two-factor-authentication.html) it seems as though this feature is only enabled for Admin accounts:

```
[...] "All features and requirements are restricted to Admin user accounts, not extended to customer accounts."
```

How do I enable it for all account types?

Comment: You can use third party extension for this functionality:
https://amasty.com/two-factor-authentication-for-magento-2.html

Comment: @Mohitchauhan The extension you suggested is not providing 2 factor authentication for customer. That is only for admin area.